# AWS resource policy on Api Gateway: anonymous is not authorized to perform invoke on resource with explicit deny

Tags: security, networking, aws-api-gateway, devops, amazon-vpc

Below resource policy on AWS API-Gateway generating this response while calling from outside as well as inside VPC

```
{"Message":"User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource: arn:aws:execute-api:ap-south-1:********2818:d5cbeh0e78/default/GET/autoimageresize-staging with an explicit deny"}
```

Resource Policy: whitelist VPC

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",<
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:ap-south-1:********2818:d5cbeh0e78/*/*/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:ap-south-1:********2818:d5cbeh0e78/*/*/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceVpc": "vpc-********"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

whereas whitelisting the resource with the concerned IP is working quite well with below resource policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:ap-south-1:********2818:d5cbeh0e78/*/*/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:ap-south-1:********2818:d5cbeh0e78/*/*/*",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "xx.xxx.xxx.xx"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Can anyone suggest where I might be going wrong, and also how can I verify what aws:SourceVpc value am I getting if not what I am expecting. And another thing, some places I am getting key as SourceVpc while other as sourceVpc in aws docs.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using cognito auth for api

Comment: No as of now, only kind of restriction added to api-gateway is through resource policy

Comment: do you have a private api gateway vpc end point

Comment: yes I have generated one....that was working fine when implemented, but due to this other API-gateway which were public was not callable from VPC. After going through aws docs : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-vpc-connections/, i disabled Private DNS name (in VPC endpoint). After this other public API-Gateway were working fine but private api were again not callable from vpc

Comment: thats the issue, once you have a private vpc end point for api gateway, you cannot call any public apis without a custom domain name

Comment: So should I delete that endpoint and restrict only using Source VPC-id?

Comment: posted an answer for you.

Comment: you cannot use sourceVpc without an endpoint

Answer (score -1, accepted):

API gateway API is public unless you create a private VPC endpoint for api gateway.

### Only when there is a private VPC endpoint exists:

- you can SourceVPC check
- SourceIp condition for private ip addresses

this is because the traffic come from internal network

### If you have a API Gateway VPC endpoint:

Once a private VPC endpoint is created, all the existing public apis in the same account can be accessed only through their custom domain.

Also make sure to redeploy the api for the resource policy changes to reflect.

Reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies-aws-condition-keys.html

Comment: does this make sense?

Comment: So in no way I can make an API-gateway private without creating vpc endpoint?

Comment: One and Only way is to whitelist all the public IP addresses of your company

Answer (score 2):

I've found that you need two things to create a private REST API.  First you need a Resource Policy which allows access from the VPC.  Then you need to create a VPC Endpoint in the VPC that is trying to access the private REST API.

When troubleshooting/revising a Resource Policy, the following steps must be executed in order.

1. Save the Resource Policy.
2. Re-deploy the API (Resources - Actions | Deploy API)
3. Wait 10 - 15 seconds.

Failure to wait for the changes to propagate will result in confusing results.

When troubleshooting these types of problems, I haven't found the API Gateway logs to be that useful.  There is usually a single entry that says "The client is not authorized to perform this operation" which is analogous to HTTP 403 (Forbidden).